# No mostrar informacion si una url da 404 NodeJS

Tags: nodejs

Buenas, hay forma de hacer que si esta url de donde se obtienen las licencias da 404 en lugar de dar errores, directamente diga no se encuentra licencia o no muestre nada, en la consola.

```js
getFromGithub: function(allRepos, callback){
  var self = this;

  var apiRequest = api('/repos/' + self.settings.org + '/' + self.repo + '/contents/package.json', {
   token: self.settings.gitToken
  });

  apiRequest.on('data', function(response) {
   self.reposParsed = JSON.stringify(allRepos);

   var packageJSON = new PackageJSON(self.settings, self.reposParsed);
   packageJSON.parseFromString(response.content, function(){
    self.getLicenseTree(packageJSON, function(err){
     if(err)
      return callback(err, null);

     self.licenses = packageJSON.list;

     callback(null, self.licenses);
    });
   });
  });

  apiRequest.on('error', function(err) {
   console.log(err);
   callback(err, null);
  });
 },
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes Agregar en tu router la siguiente linea depende de como se llame la variable de tu servidor en este caso app.
Si no encuentra la ruta te enviar error 404 en tu Nvegador

```
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.send('Pagina No Encontrada', 404);
});
```

Comment: No funciona, ademas lo que quiero es que si no encuentra la licencia devuelva esa palabra en la consola, no en el navegador. Esta app es un license server